# Wifi Adapter Not Working In Kali-Linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux, usb-device, airmon-ng

My Wifi-Adapter is TL-WN823N, initially my pc did not recognize anything. So i installed two solutions finded googling:

- [rtl8192cu-fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)
- [rtl8192eu-linux-driver](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver)

Now my Wifi adapter is recognized by the Kali-Linux system (4.7.0), but it does not work.

> airmon-ng start wlan1

```
PHY     Interface   Driver      Chipset

null    wlan1       ??????
```

These are some commands that i launched to looking for a solution:

> lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2357:0109
```

> lshw

```
 *-usb:1
               description: Generic USB device
               product: 802.11n NIC
               vendor: Realtek
               physical id: 3
               bus info: usb@1:3
               version: 2.00
               serial: 00e04c000001
               capabilities: usb-2.10
               configuration: driver=rtl8192eu maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/
```

> tail -f -n 0 /var/log/messages

```
Nov  3 18:57:18 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.096552] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.281427] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0109
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.281430] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.281431] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.281433] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.281434] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282035] RTL871X: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282035] usb_endpoint_descriptor(0):
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282038] RTL871X: bLength=7
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282039] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282039] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=84
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282040] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282041] RTL871X: bInterval=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282042] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_in = 4
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282043] RTL871X: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282043] usb_endpoint_descriptor(1):
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282044] RTL871X: bLength=7
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282045] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282046] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282046] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282047] RTL871X: bInterval=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282048] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282049] RTL871X: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282049] usb_endpoint_descriptor(2):
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282050] RTL871X: bLength=7
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282051] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282051] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=6
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282052] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282053] RTL871X: bInterval=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282054] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 6
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282055] RTL871X: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282055] usb_endpoint_descriptor(3):
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282056] RTL871X: bLength=7
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282056] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282057] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=87
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282058] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=64
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282059] RTL871X: bInterval=3
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282060] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_int_in = 7, Interval = 3
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282061] RTL871X: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282061] usb_endpoint_descriptor(4):
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282062] RTL871X: bLength=7
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282062] RTL871X: bDescriptorType=5
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282063] RTL871X: bEndpointAddress=8
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282064] RTL871X: wMaxPacketSize=512
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282065] RTL871X: bInterval=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282065] RTL871X: RT_usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out = 8
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282067] RTL871X: nr_endpoint=5, in_num=2, out_num=3
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282067] 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282068] RTL871X: USB_SPEED_HIGH
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282104] RTL871X: CHIP TYPE: RTL8192E
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282110] RTL871X: register rtw_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282150] RTL871X: ReadChipVersion192e 0xF0 = 0xc441135 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282156] RTL871X: Chip Version Info: CHIP_8192E_Normal_Chip_SMIC_B_CUT_2T2R_RomVer(0)
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282158] RTL871X: RF_Type is 2!!
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282160] RTL871X: _ConfigChipOutEP_8192E OutEpQueueSel(0x07), OutEpNumber(3) 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282161] RTL871X: ====> ReadAdapterInfo8192EU
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.282184] RTL871X: Boot from EFUSE, Autoload OK !
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338870] RTL871X: EEPROM ID=0x8129
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338879] RTL871X: VID = 0x2357, PID = 0x0109
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338881] RTL871X: Customer ID: 0x00, SubCustomer ID: 0xCD
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338884] RTL871X: hal_ReadMACAddress_8192EU MAC Address from EFUSE = 18:a6:f7:12:eb:08
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338887] RTL871X: Hal_ReadPowerSavingMode8192E...bHWPwrPindetect(0)-bHWPowerdown(0) ,bSupportRemoteWakeup(1)
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338889] RTL871X: ### PS params=>  power_mgnt(1),usbss_enable(0) ###
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338893] RTL871X: EEPROMRegulatory = 0x1 TxPwrCalibrateRate=0x0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338894] RTL871X: Board Type: Dongle or WIFI only Module 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338898] RTL871X: mlmepriv.ChannelPlan = 0x21
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338899] RTL871X: CrystalCap: 0x1b
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338900] RTL871X: ThermalMeter = 0x23
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338901] RTL871X: SWAS: bHwAntDiv = 0, TRxAntDivType = ff
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338902] RTL871X: pHalData->PAType_2G is 0x0, pHalData->ExternalPA_2G = 0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338903] RTL871X: pHalData->LNAType_2G is 0x0, pHalData->ExternalLNA_2G = 0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.338904] RTL871X: ReadAdapterInfo8192EU <====
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339008] RTL871X: init_channel_set ChannelPlan ID 21 Chan num:13  
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339802] RTL871X: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~~~~
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339818] RTL871X: pwrctrlpriv.bSupportRemoteWakeup~~~[1]~~~
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339824] RTL871X: can't get autopm: 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339828] RTL871X: rtw_macaddr_cfg MAC Address  = 18:a6:f7:12:eb:08
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339830] RTL871X: bDriverStopped:1, bSurpriseRemoved:0, bup:0, hw_init_completed:0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.339872] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan1)
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.1747] (wlan1): driver supports SSID scans (scan_capa 0x3F).
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.1749] (wlan1): using WEXT for WiFi device control
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.341084] RTL871X: _rtw_drv_register_netdev, MAC Address (if1) = 18:a6:f7:12:eb:08
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.342813] RTL871X: LeaveAllPowerSaveMode(wlan1): bup=0 Skip!
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.342827] RTL871X: rtw_wx_set_scan: bDriverStopped=1, bup=0, hw_init_completed=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.1763] manager: (wlan1): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.404413] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.404438] RTL871X: +871x_drv - drv_open, bup=0
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.404440] RTL871X: ==>_InitPowerOn_8192EU 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.406520] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E: bMacPwrCtrlOn=1
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.406717] RTL871X:  ===> FirmwareDownload88E() fw source from Header.
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.406720] RTL871X: FirmwareDownload8192E fw:NIC, size: 31818
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.2360] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/wlan1, iface: wlan1)
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.2360] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/wlan1, iface: wlan1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <info>  [1478195839.2361] device (wlan1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.406722] RTL871X: FirmwareDownload8192E: fw_ver=19 fw_subver=0 sig=0x92e1
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.437964] RTL871X: polling_fwdl_chksum: Checksum report OK! (1, 0ms), REG_MCUFWDL:0x00070305
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.438409] RTL871X: =====> _8051Reset8192E(): 8051 reset success .
Nov  3 18:57:19 Koine-Paolo kernel: [  171.462916] RTL871X: _FWFreeToGo8192E: Polling FW ready OK! (508, 24ms), REG_MCUFWDL:0x000702c6
Nov  3 18:57:19 Koine-Paolo kernel: [  171.462925] RTL871X: FWDL success. write_fw:1, 56ms
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.467718] RTL871X: ===> phy_BB8192E_Config_ParaFile() EEPROMRegulatory 1
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  171.482715] RTL871X: PHY_BBConfig8192E ==> CrystalCap:0x1b 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.022213] RTL871X: Auto InitLLTTable8192E success 
Nov  3 18:57:19 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.032385] RTL871X: pDM_Odm TxPowerTrackControl = 1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.189231] RTL871X: phy_SpurCalibration_8192E =>AFE_PHASE_SEL 
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.249968] RTL871X: ===FixSpur NOT Pass!
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.620896] RTL871X: wlan1 MAC Address from REG_MACID = 18:a6:f7:12:eb:08
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.620898] RTL871X: rtl8192eu_hal_init in 1220ms
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.620900] RTL871X: wlan1Port-0  set opmode = 2
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.627095] RTL871X: MAC Address = 18:a6:f7:12:eb:08
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.627132] RTL871X: -871x_drv - drv_open, bup=1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.627188] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.627343] RTL871X: (2)871x_drv - drv_close, bup=1, hw_init_completed=1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.633770] RTL871X: indicate disassoc
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.633789] RTL871X: SetHwReg8192E(wlan1) HW_VAR_BASIC_RATE: BrateCfg(0x15d)
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.633791] RTL871X: +rtl8192e_set_FwJoinBssReport_cmd(wlan1): iface_type=0 mstatus(0)
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.633945] RTL871X: -871x_drv - drv_close, bup=1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC NetworkManager[702]: <warn>  [1478195840.5662] device (wlan1): set-hw-addr: new MAC address 36:26:4F:13:8B:1B not successfully set (scanning)
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.734440] RTL871X: +871x_drv - drv_open, bup=1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.734446] RTL871X: -871x_drv - drv_open, bup=1
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.734464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742328] RTL871X: [rtw_wx_set_pmkid] IW_PMKSA_FLUSH!
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742334] RTL871X: set_mode = IW_MODE_INFRA
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742350] RTL871X: set bssid:00:00:00:00:00:00
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742361] RTL871X: =>rtw_wx_set_essid
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742362] RTL871X: ssid=g�isQ�J�)ͺ����F|�T����vZ.c3�ɚ, len=32
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742364] RTL871X: set ssid [g�isQ�J�)ͺ����F|�T����vZ.c3�ɚUw-�] fw_state=0x00000008
Nov  3 18:57:20 KALI-PC kernel: [  172.742364] RTL871X: Set SSID under fw_state=0x00000008
```

Comment: You need to install the ath9k drivers as this uses the Atheros card - This link will help you install them - http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc/
Usually on the later versions of kali, this should be natively installed, but sometimes it is done manually, and the documentation should help you form the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help avoid this, I make the live usb, with Rufus on Windows and extract the Debian non free firmware to the firmware folder on the USB. Then when installing Kali have the wifi card plugged in. It should load the non free firmware for it.